# aria-hidden on a TH

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

We have a large complex grid where I want to give sighted and non sighted users a different experience. It's a custom control which has grids within grids. It's fine for sighted users and has been around for ~20 years but would be difficult to understand if using a screen reader. There is zero chance of a redesign. Hiding the control and having a separate control for screen readers is also a no-no as other than that it's perfectly usable for both

I want, in the example below, to not read out the header for the first cell in screen readers.

If I use aria-hidden then the TH is removed from the flow and screen readers will read out the wrong heading

You can't have aria-value with no value

I'd like to replace the headers so one relates to the cell and other isn't read out

Is there any way of achieving this?

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th aria-hidden="true">egg</th>
      <th>banana</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th aria-hidden="true">plant</th>
      <th>tree</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td tabindex="0">
        cat
      </td>
      <td tabindex="0">
        dog
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's the output of the screen reader. Note that the header above dog isn't read out, the header above cat is read out a banana tree, which is the wrong header

table
dog  row 3  column 2
cat  row 3  banana
tree  column 1

Comment: Nothing. I want it to be as if the TH was empty

Comment: When the screen reader sets focus to the table, and uses the arrow keys to move between the TDs. When it hits cat it should just read out cat, when it hits dog it should read out dog and tree. It shouldn't read out dog and banana, which it presently does using aria-hiiden

Comment: Edited the question to add the screen reader details. I want it to read cat, then dog banana tree. The dog's headers are being read on the cat. I don't want the cat to have headers

Comment: You shouldn't need to hide an header like this, that's very strange. Why do you want to hide that header for screen readers ?

Comment: It's a weird situation, a table with many headers and an inner grid which is distinguished by css colours. I fully understand that this is a complete outlier as scenarios go

Answer (score 0):

Can't believe I didn't think of this earlier

```
<th><span aria-hidden>text</span></th>
```

Keep the TH but wrap the contents

Although I still think it would be nice if accessibility had something like visibility: hidden, although I grant this is probably a niche case